# Simple Javascript calculations

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to create a simple page that calculates the total cost of the shirts either individually or when they are added together for a final total. I think I am very close but I cant get the total to add or display in the input box. Maybe you guys can help me out. Its for a final project for class and my teacher cant seem to help me either. Please Internet help me!!!!!

here is my code: The start of the function is in the head and then the calling for the function is towards the bottom.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Shirts</title>
  <link href="styles/eccomercestyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript">

    // cost of items in dollars
    var costShirt = 10; 



      function updateTotal(){
        var tot = 0;
        tot += f.blackShirt.value * costBlack +
    f.whiteShirt.value * costWhite +
    f.blueShirt.value * costBlue;
        document.getElementById("cost").value = tot.toFixed(2);
      }

  </script>
  </head>


  <body>
<div id="logo"> <a href="index.html"> <img src="instalogo.png" width="493" height="91" alt="Return home"/> </a> </div>
<h1 style="font-family: Segoe, 'Segoe UI', 'DejaVu Sans', 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: medium; color: #FF7208;">Choose a style.</h1>
<div id="container">
    <table width="200" border="1" bordercolor="black">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="blackcottonPNG.png" width="160" height="200" alt="Choose a quantity"/>

            <br>
      <form action="" method="POST" name="myForm" id="myForm">
         <label for="blackShirt"><strong>Black T $10.00 x </strong></label>
            <select id="blackShirt">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
              </select>
            </br>
         </td>

        <td><img src="whitecottonPNG.png" width="160" height="200" alt="Choose a quantity"/>
                       <br>
       <label for="whiteShirt"><strong>Black T $10.00 x </strong></label>
       <select id="whiteShirt">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
              </select>
            </br>
          </td>

        <td><img src="bluecottonPNG.png" width="160" height="200" alt="Choose a quantity"/>
            <br>
            <label for="blueShirt"><strong>Black T $10.00 x </strong></label>
            <select id="blueShirt">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
              </select>
            </br>
          </form></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>

    <h3>SUBTOTAL:</h3>
    <div> $
    <input type="text" id="cost" value="0" readonly size="3"/>
  </div>
    <div>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </div>
</main>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var f = document.forms['myForm'];
      var sel = document.getElementsByTagName("select");


      for(var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
        sel[i].onchange = function(){updateTotal()};
      }

     // here the form data is submitted to the server
      f.onsubmit = function(){
        alert("Your total cost will be: $" + f.cost.value);
        return false;
      }
      </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Step 1: Open your browser's console and see what errors you have. And if your teacher can't help you then you have a lousy teacher.

Comment: Tell me about it! The old teacher just up and left so he came in, his excuse is that he's a game designer not much of a coder.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the value of an element by assigning it a value. Use the `setAttribute` method for this. So, you chould change

```
document.getElementById("cost").value = tot.toFixed(2);
```

to

```
document.getElementById("cost").setAttribute('value', tot.toFixed(2));
```

Should do the trick...